# Google sheets: search source table, return only values matching criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

In Google Sheets:

Column A has a marker, column B has movie titles

I want to search the below table for movies that have been seen (column A = "x"), and populate column C with seen movies, with no blanks.

Source data:

- Column A  Column B
- Seen it? Titles
- x Jack Ryan Shadow Recruit BD
- x Indiana Jones Movies BD
- n Harry Potter Movies BD
- n Interstellar BD
- x The Rocketeer CD
- x Fantasia CD
- n Robin Hood movie CD
- n The Wolverine BD
- x Stargate Ark fo Truth BD
- x The Lord of the Rings cartoon CD
- n Batman Movies BD DVD

desired result in column C

- Jack Ryan Shadow Recruit BD
- Indiana Jones Movies BD
- The Rocketeer CD
- Fantasia CD
- Stargate Ark fo Truth BD
- The Lord of the Rings cartoon CD

I believe I need to use array formulas, but don't know how.

I can use vlookup or index(match()), but this gives me a list full of blanks or #NA's etc.

I want the resultant list without all the blanks, so essentially filtered for unique values removing blanks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en):

Example:

```
=FILTER(A2:B,A2:A="x")
```